# ggsave always opens a graphics window after upgrading to ggplot2 version3.0.0

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggsave() opens a graphics window in R after I upgraded ggplot2 to version 3.0.0.

Function has width and height parameters, but it still opens up and it is very ugly inside a package.

How can I supress this graphic device?

```
p1 <- ggplot()
ggsave(plot= p1, filename = '/home/home/Desktop/Folder/plot.png', width = 5, height = 5)
```

Comment: This is probably worth bringing to the attention of the ggplot2 developers on their github issues page: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide your `sessionInfo()`. Have you got the latest R version? Have you started a clean R session? What do you expect to happen with `p1<-ggplot()` ?

Comment: seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2758) in ggplot2. `p1 <- ggplot()` creates an empty plot. The problem is that an inactive graphic devices is opened when you want to save this blank plot using `ggsave()`.

Comment: I installed the developer version from gitHub and problems are solved.

`packageVersion('ggplot2')`
`[1] ‘3.0.0.9000’`